# is there a way to print debug info to the log?

Tags: python, debugging, logging

I've got a python program that passes some info to a site for parsing.  it's not working but I'm not sure why. is there a way to put diagnostic info at certain places that will print to the log?

Answer (score 1):

You could use python [logging](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) to write a logfile.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
```